# SQL Update / Alter or Insert?

Tags: sql-server

I created a database called Company and a table called EmployeesTD and forgot to add auto increment to my EmployeeID row , how do I update my table to add auto increment

Comment: are there any data in the table?

Comment: I believe you can drop tho column and re-add it as identity and have it auto-populate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create new table with a temporary name and the auto increment field

2) Move all data from the old table into new table (using identity_insert)

3) Drop the old table

4) Rename the new table to it's original name

(Don't forget to add your indexes if you have any. Add them afterwards if you do to avoid unnecessary index rebuilding.)

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table t1
add somename int identity(1,1)
```

or else

```
create table dummytable 
(
id int identity(1,1)
somecols --

)

insert into dummytable
select colnames from orginaltable
```

finally add indexes and rename dummy to original

I would go with second approach,if table has large data,since first operation may take a lock on table totally

Answer (score 0):

You can just run this `ALTER TABLE` query

```
ALTER TABLE EmployeesTD ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Even if you have records in `EmployeesTD` table the above statement will populate Unique values for each row

Another approach using `Identity` function

```
-- 1. create a temporary table 
SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS id,
       *
INTO   temp_EmployeesTD
FROM   EmployeesTD

-- 2. drop the orginal table
DROP TABLE EmployeesTD

-- 3. rename the temporary table to orginal table
EXEC Sp_rename
  'temp_EmployeesTD',
  'EmployeesTD' 

-- 4. Recreate the indexes if any
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name MODIFY COLUMN col_name INT auto_increment
```